# How to search in `more` screens?

Tags: navigation

Some commands, for example `:syn` and `:scriptnames` show a "--more-- screen" which is confusing to navigate. Contrary to what `man more` says, pressing `/` doesn't seem to work to search for text. Instead pressing it shows `-- More -- SPACE/d/j: screen/page/line down, b/u/k: up, q: quit` at bottom, which is different from the behaviour in `more` (which also doesn't seem to work properly in my system, which i never noticed since i always used `less`). This is very awkward and confusing, how to navigate in these windows?

Comment: For completeness, note that this is vim's builtin pager which looks similar to the unix `more` utility but is in fact internal to vim.  That is why its behaviour is discordant with what you might expect when reading `man more`.

Answer (score 3):

To see the commands available from that prompt go to `:h pager`. Here's the bulk of the content:

```
Type                         effect
<CR> or <NL> or j or <Down>  one more line
d                            down a page (half a screen)
<Space> or f or <PageDown>   down a screen
G                            down all the way, until the hit-enter
                             prompt

<BS> or k or <Up>           one line back
u                           up a page (half a screen)
b or <PageUp>               back a screen
g                           back to the start

q, <Esc> or CTRL-C          stop the listing
:                           stop the listing and enter a
                            command-line
<C-Y>                       yank (copy) a modeless selection to
                            the clipboard ("* and "+ registers)
{menu-entry}                what the menu is defined to in
                            Cmdline-mode.
<LeftMouse>                 next page (*)

Any other key causes the meaning of the keys to be displayed.
```

Then there's the somewhat obscure `g<` command...

```
The |g<| command can be used to see the last page of previous command output.
This is especially useful if you accidentally typed <Space> at the hit-enter prompt.
```

I know I often accidentally exit out of the last page of output so `g<` is a nice little command to get back there without having to think much about it.

Ah, but you asked about searching. As you can see `/` is not available. Your best bet is probably to use the `:filter` command...

```
:filter /pattern/ :scriptnames
```

...for example. Unfortunately, `:filter` doesn't work with all commands. Your other example, `:syn`, to name one. At this point we're left with only ad hoc solutions. If you want to use `/` then it'll be quite crude...

```
:redir @x | silent :syn | redir END
```

That'll put the `:syn` command's output into register `x`. (`:silent` ensure the full output is dumped without pause/prompting.) Now go paste the register contents in an empty buffer and search it. Like I said, crude.

**Update:**

A more fully realized and robust take on the `:redir` approach can be found here: [Redirect the output of a Vim or external command into a scratch buffer](https://gist.github.com/romainl/eae0a260ab9c135390c30cd370c20cd7)

Conveniently, it's encapsulated in a single user command named `:Redir`.

Comment: `:filter /pattern/ :syn` seems to have always same output as `:syn`. Help page on `:filter` says only some commands support filtering and `:syn` doesn't seem to be one of those..

Comment: Ah, I think I tested `:scriptnames` and then mixed them up in my head. I'm pretty sure there's no straightforward way to do it for commands that don't work with `:filter`. I have a couple ad hoc methods that you can use which I'll post when I get a minute.

Comment: Also `:new | put =execute(…)`

Comment: Yes, there are all kinds of ways to do it. All but the way that makes the most sense (i.e. search in pager.) :P